# Right free of memory while using libudev

Tags: c++, linux, udev

I use libudev to detect usb devices.
Initialise monitor and filter:

```
struct udev* udev = udev_new();
if (udev == nullptr) { /* error handling */ }

struct udev_monitor* usb = udev_monitor_new_from_netlink(udev, "udev");
udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype(usb, "usb", NULL);
udev_monitor_enable_receiving(usb);

while(! canceled) { /* setup fd, poll fd, process result */ }
```

Then I release the allocated ressources with:

```
udev_monitor_unref(usb);
udev_unref(udev);
```

But sometimes I get

> *** glibc detected *** ./usbtest: corrupted double-linked list: 0x084cc5d0 ***

I tried to use:

```
free(usb);
free(udev);
```

But then valgrind complaint about memory leaks.

What the right way to release the memory in this case?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/libudev/libudev-udev.html) it should be sufficient to use:

```
udev_unref(udev);
```

and [here](ftp://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/libudev/libudev-udev-monitor.html) says:

```
udev_monitor_unref(usb);
```

should free that resource. If that gives you a double free, then something is not right, and you really need to debug that issue, not try to work around it by other means.